# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: not an error (code 0 SQLITE_OK)

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

I'm using this library to save , retreive and delete data , but whenever i try to perform any of those operations , it throws the above mentionned error , and this is the library that i'm using

```
  implementation 'com.github.p32929:AndroidEasySQL-Library:1.4.1'
```

- This is my code

```
 private fun deleteCartDetails() {
        val easyDB = EasyDB.init(this,"ITEMS_DB")
                .setTableName("CART_TABLE")
                .addColumn(Column("item_id", *arrayOf("text","unique")))
                .addColumn(Column("item_productId", *arrayOf("text","not null")))
                .addColumn(Column("item_title", *arrayOf("text","not null")))
                .addColumn(Column("item_price", *arrayOf("text","not null")))
                .addColumn(Column("item_cost", *arrayOf("text","not null")))
                .addColumn(Column("item_quantity", *arrayOf("text","not null")))

        easyDB.deleteAllDataFromTable()
    }
```

any help would be appreciated guys , thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you are missing the line that creates the table before you are trying to delete rows from the table.

That is the **`.doneTableColumn()`** which should follow the `.addColumn`'s

So try :-

```
private fun deleteCartDetails() {
    val easyDB = EasyDB.init(this,"ITEMS_DB")
            .setTableName("CART_TABLE")
            .addColumn(Column("item_id", *arrayOf("text","unique")))
            .addColumn(Column("item_productId", *arrayOf("text","not null")))
            .addColumn(Column("item_title", *arrayOf("text","not null")))
            .addColumn(Column("item_price", *arrayOf("text","not null")))
            .addColumn(Column("item_cost", *arrayOf("text","not null")))
            .addColumn(Column("item_quantity", *arrayOf("text","not null")))
            .doneTableColumn() //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED

    easyDB.deleteAllDataFromTable()
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much , i was missing that line , your help is appreciated